# How can I unapprove edits?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I just made a mistake by approving this edit:

https://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/93132

because I confused left side and right side...

Is there a possibility to edit your own review?

Answer (score 6):

If you have the reputation to review suggested edits, you have the reputation to pull up the post in question and hit the rollback button.

(If a second person has approved it, that is. This is, of course, part of the reason that it takes two approvals for a suggestion to go through.)

Comment: Thx for the reminder. I should not review before going to bed. Good thing we have the double check